# A equação a seguir respeita a sintaxe da Álgebra Relacional?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

```
π Nome.Empregado (σ Empregado.IdentEmp = TrabalhoNo.IdentEmp ^
TrabalhaNo.ProjNum = Projeto.ProjNum ^
Nome = ‘Banco de Dados’ ((Empregado x TrabalhoNo) x Projeto))
```

Mais especificamente na parte que eu faço um produto cartesiano "triplo" ((Empregado X TrabalhaNo) x Projeto)). É possível?

Comment: Mas o MySQL ou o Oracle implementam álgebra relacional? Nada impede que o produto cartesiano envolva mais de duas relações.

Comment: Creio que não; não tinha tag para álgebra relacional e não pude criar a tag devido à minha reputação.